# IISexpress reset and set configuration directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I am using IIS8 express server for visual studio to debug my web application. In mid-time, I reinstalled IIS8 as I found that IIS8 express creating it's 'Config,Logs,TraceLogFiles' folders under desktop not under C:/username/document/IISExpress file path as default. And as a result I am facing problems to debug my Visual Studio web application. its throwing error like 'process with an id of is not running' and cannot explore project solution as I tried some solution. Still I could not set the actual file path for IIS8Express. how I can set reset IIS8express and set default config path to C:/username/document/IISExpress

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old question, but had the same problem. After doing a backup, I ended up removing the content of `%userprofile%\My Documents\IIS Express` folder, recreating the config folder, and copy the content of the templates under '%programfiles%\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer' to that `%userprofile%\My Documents\IIS Express\config`

After restarting IISExpress and Visual Studio 2013 the problem disappeared and iisexpress was now being started by visual studio.

Of course, this clears up everything and resets all you configurations, but after comparing the backup with the new generated files, the issue seems to be the missing `serverAutoStart="true"` under the `site` node.